# How to join pandas dataframes on two keys with a prioritized key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

How can I left join two pandas dataframes (`df1`, `df2`) on two keys (`bla1`, `bla2`), where the `bla2` key should be used whenever it's not null (see last two rows in `df1`)?

**Pseudo-code**

if `bla2` is not null then join `bla` on `bla2`

else join `bla` on `bla1`

**Dataframes**

**df1**

```
| bla1 | bla2 | a   | b   |
|------|------|-----|-----|
| 1    |      | ... | ... |
| 2    |      | ... | ... |
| 3    |      | ... | ... |
| 4    | 7    | ... | ... |
| 5    | 8    | ... | ... |
```

**+ df2**

```
| bla | x   | y   | z   |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1   | ... | ... | ... |
| 2   | ... | ... | ... |
| 3   | ... | ... | ... |
| 7   | ... | ... | ... |
| 8   | ... | ... | ... |
```

**= df3**

```
| bla1 | bla2 | a   | b   | x   | y   | z   |
|------|------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1    |      | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2    |      | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3    |      | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5    | 7    | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 4    | 8    | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
```

Comment: It might help to post sample code definitions of df1 and df2.

Comment: is it empty string, none or nan in bla2 column?

Comment: @AartiGoyal nan

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First create a new column to combine both columns.

```
df1["new_column"] = df1.bla2.fillna(df1.bla1);
```

Then join both frames and drop extra created columns.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", left_on="new_column", right_on="bla").drop(["new_column", "bla"], axis=1)
```

Comment: Should I replace `inner` with `left` if I want to left join `df2` on `df1`?

Comment: Sure if you think df2 may not have all records but in results you want to include all records of df1.

Comment: You could do this on one step using `assign` like this:  `df1.assign(bla1 = df1['bla2'].fillna(df1['bla1']).astype(int)).merge(df2, on='bla1')`

Comment: Yeap.. It is same thing.